# Unable to get the pagination crawler to work Python3

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I m trying to use the scrapy module in python to scrape the details, but I am currently stuck on trying to get the pagination crawler to work. I'm getting the output partially right, but as I said previously, it is not scraping from the following pages on the [website](https://www.sunwaymedical.com/find-a-doctor/search/?specialty=&doctor=&name=)

```
import scrapy
from time import sleep
from ..items import SunwayscrapyItem


class SunwaySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sunway"
    page_number = 20
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.sunwaymedical.com/find-a-doctor/']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.sunwaymedical.com/find-a-doctor/search/0/? 
specialty=&doctor=&name=' 
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    # all_details = response.css('.col-lg-9')
    # for details in all_details:
    for SunwaySpider.page_number in range(0, 220, 20):
        items = SunwayscrapyItem()
        next_page = "https://www.sunwaymedical.com/find-a-doctor/search/" + str(
            SunwaySpider.page_number) + "/?specialty=&doctor=&name="
        if SunwaySpider.page_number < 220:
            name = response.css('.doctor_name a::text').extract()
            specialty = response.css('.doc_label3:nth-child(4)::text').extract()
            language = response.css('.doc_label3:nth-child(8)::text').extract()
            gender = response.css('.doc_label3:nth-child(12)::text').extract()
            qualifications = response.css('.doc_label3:nth-child(16)::text').extract()
            location = response.css('.doc_label3:nth-child(20)::text').extract()
            contact = response.css('.doc_label3 a::text').extract()

            items['Name'] = name
            items['Specialty'] = list(map(str.strip, specialty))
            items['Languages'] = list(map(str.strip, language))
            items['Gender'] = list(map(str.strip, gender))
            items['Qualifications'] = list(map(str.strip, qualifications))
            items['Location'] = list(map(str.strip, location))
            items['Contact'] = list(map(str.strip, contact))
            yield items
        sleep(3)
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: You must yield from within the loop (indent `yield items` further). Currently, you are overwritting the contents of `items` (which is actually a single item) every time, and only yielding the data of the last item. You should also rename `items` to `item` and move `items = SunwayscrapyItem()` to right below the `for`, also further indented.

Consider getting yourself more familiar with Python and Scrapy before you continue.

Comment: @Gallaecio Thank you for the advice. I realized that after saving it as a csv and have made amendments but I still can't seem to get the pagination to work. Would that be because as you said I m not familiar with python and scrapy or is it something else? The output log seems to keep outputting only the first-page multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating the structure of pagination properly. It is not advised to implement pagination and the yielding of items in a single method. Take a look at the sample code below:

```
class AnswersMicrosoft(CrawlSpider):
name = 'answersmicrosoft'
allowed_domains = ['answers.microsoft.com']
start_urls = ['https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us']

listings_css = ['#categoryListGridMed', '.nav-links']
products_css = ['#threads .c-card .thread-title']

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css=products_css), callback='parse_item'),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css=listings_css), callback='parse_pagination'),

)

def parse_pagination(self, response):
    forum_id_css = '#currentForumId::attr(value)'
    forum_id = response.css(forum_id_css).get()

    url = 'https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/forum/forumthreadlist?forumId=' + forum_id
    yield Request(url, callback=self.get_max_page, meta={'url': response.url})

def get_max_page(self, response):
    max_page_css = '.currentMaxPage::attr(value)'
    max_page = int(response.css(max_page_css).get())
    url = response.url

    for page in range(max_page):
        updated_url = add_or_replace_parameter(url, 'page', page)
        yield Request(updated_url, callback=self.parse)

def parse_item(self, response):
    article = AnswersMicrosoftItem()
    article["title"] = self.get_title(response).strip()
    article["url"] = response.url
    article["votes"] = self.get_votes(response)
    article["replies"] = self.get_replies(response)
    article["category"] = self.get_category(response)
    article["views"] = self.get_views(response)
    article["date"] = self.get_date(response).strip()
    article["last_updated"] = self.get_last_updated(response).strip()
    yield article
```

See that parse_pagination is implemented and how rules are implemented to call the method. If you are novice and don't know much about rules, I prefer you give them a look. They will help you **alot** in your journey ahead. Also, try to implement a modular approach. 
The `rules` above call only two things; if they see a product, they call `parse_item` and if they see the next page, they call `parse_pagination`.

I hope you understand my point. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining. You are right I am a total novice at python and coding in general. I ll take your advice and read up more on what you said.

Comment: Great! If the this solved your question, please choose it as the answer.